# Необходимо держать приложение в фокусе

Tags: windows, windows-7

Есть некоторая scada, у которой работает звук, только когда она в фокусе, если появляется стороннее окно или видна нижняя панель - звука не будет. Таким образом необходимо периодически переводить фокус на скаду. В гугле нашел лишь программку windows on top, которая не дает развернуть другие программы, но при этом дает появиться нижней панели.
Можно ли автоматизировать перевод фокуса на приложения с некоторой периодичностью?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал созданием скрипта в autohotkey:

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2
Loop
{
  WinActivate,WinTitle ; title is case sensitive
  Sleep,1000 ; wait one second (time is specified in milliseconds)
}
```

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28522341/How-to-always-keep-focus-on-a-Win7-app.html